# cross postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I chose one row to click select button in grid view and click to submit button to go next page. Then, I want to get selection grid view id from grid view page. How I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to pass the selection as a query argument to the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridView OnRowCommand event to fetch the datasource bounded to that particular row. From that you can take the for that particular row. Pass this to the second page either through querystring or session .

Thanks